# Nginx reverse proxy works only a few times, then fails

Tags: meteor, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I deployed an meteor app to a digital ocean droplet and mapped that to a domain. I'm pretty new to server management so I followed a guide to set up a reverse proxy with nginx to point to the correct port (the meteor app is served on port 3000).

I created a file called `trackburnr.com` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` with this content:

```
server {  
 listen 80;
 server_name trackburnr.com;

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }
}
```

And start / restart the nginx service.

Now, here's the catch. If I navigate to trackburnr.com:3000, it always works. So I'm confident my droplet and DNS record on the domain works fine.

If I navigate to trackburnr.com, it seems like it's working fine, but if I refresh the page after a few minutes or navigate to it with another browser, it returns the "page not found" page from my internet provider.

If I restart the service, it usually works fine for a another few minutes and then stops working again.

There are several guides about this as it's a popular setup for deploying meteor apps, but they all use this same approach.

Following another answer in here I tried setting `proxy_pass` as a variable beforehand and passing it, but with no success.

Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Comment: Sounds to me like your application is crashing. What does the logs say?

Comment: If you follow the digitalocean meteor deploy tutorial there's a much fuller nginx configuration. I've never had issues with that config

Comment: Doesn't look like a crash, because the app logs are clean and the nginx logs show normal access events - but just when I'm able to visit the address. When I get the "page not found" nothing gets written to the logs because it's like I've never visited that page.

Since I deployed using meteor-up I've reset the droplet and I'm trying again following their [guide](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/wiki/Using-Meteor-Up-with-NginX-vhosts)

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. My domain provider had an DNS redirect set up which redirected `trackburner.com` to `www.trackburnr.com`. Obviously that subdomain wasn't mapped in nginx.

I revered the redirect so that `www` redirected to the non-www version and that seemed to do the trick.

After that I was incurring in `400 Bad Request`. I attribute this to the google analytics code in my header which made the cookies too big. I fixed this by adding the `large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;` to my server tag in the nginx conf file. More info about that [here](http://cnedelcu.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/dealing-with-nginx-400-bad-request-http.html)